# take all the values from database and store it in a string array

Tags: java, android, xml

I have made a vegetable class where i will take all the data from database class and i need to store data in a string array.
Say i have items onion,potato with there price 50,80 in database.
now I need to take those values from database and store in my main class as

```
String items[] = {"onion","potato"};
String price[] = {"50","80"};
```

My main class is as follows:

```
package com.ku.bazzar;

public class VegetableActivity extends Activity {
//String items[];
//String price[];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vegetables_info);
```

I tried something like below:

```
Vegetablesdatabase info = new Vegetablesdatabase(this);
        info.open();
        items[] = { info.getvegetable();}
     price[]= { info.getprice();}
        info.close();
```

I know this is wrong:

```
 items[] = { info.getvegetable();}
         price[]= { info.getprice();}
```

So anyone can please teach me to make string array of the items and price and also create a method `getvegetable()` and `getprice()` in my vegetabledatabase file?

I have made a database class as follows

```
    package com.ku.bazzar;


    public class Vegetablesdatabase {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_VEGETABLES = "vegetables";
    public static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="ITEM_VEGETABLES";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="VEGETABLES";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION= 1;

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourdatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
        KEY_ROWID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_VEGETABLES + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                    KEY_PRICE + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
            );

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

        }


    }

    public Vegetablesdatabase(Context c){
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public Vegetablesdatabase open() throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourdatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public long createEntry(String vegetables, String price) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_VEGETABLES, vegetables);
        cv.put(KEY_PRICE, price);
        return ourdatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    }



    public String getvegetablename(long l)throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID,KEY_VEGETABLES,KEY_PRICE};
        Cursor c= ourdatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l,null, null, null, null);
        if(c!= null){
            c.moveToFirst();
            String name = c.getString(1);
            return name;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getvegetableprice(long l)throws SQLException {
        String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID,KEY_VEGETABLES,KEY_PRICE};
        Cursor c= ourdatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l,null, null, null, null);
        if(c!= null){
            c.moveToFirst();
            String name = c.getString(2);
            return name;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void updateentry(long lRow, String vegename, String vegeprice) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cvupdate = new ContentValues();
        cvupdate.put(KEY_VEGETABLES, vegename);
        cvupdate.put(KEY_PRICE, vegeprice);
        ourdatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvupdate, KEY_ROWID + "=" + lRow, null);

    }

    public String getData() {
        String [] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID,KEY_VEGETABLES,KEY_PRICE};
        Cursor C =ourdatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";
        int iRow = C.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int ivegetable = C.getColumnIndex(KEY_VEGETABLES);
        int iprice = C.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE);

        for(C.moveToFirst(); !C.isAfterLast(); C.moveToNext()){
            result = result + C.getString(iRow) + " " + C.getString(ivegetable) + " " + C.getString(iprice) + "\n";

        }
        return result;
    }

    public void deleteEntry(long lRow1) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ourdatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + lRow1, null);


    }
   }
```

Comment: I would suggest you use a [java.util.ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T[]%29).

Comment: You don't have to write answers to explain things. Please update your question

Answer (score 0):

String array can be initialized directly with values during declaration. but, when you want to  initialize the values by invoking a method, this should be followed

```
    String[] strArray = new String[5]; //Ex: 5 is the size of the array
    Vegetablesdatabase info = new Vegetablesdatabase(this);
    for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++){
    strArray[i] = info.getvegetable();
    }

//strArray is filled with values after the loop
```

Please note that `info.getvegetable()` should return a String literal. if you don't want a fixed size collection, go for a list implementation.

You have to go for ArrayList since you don't have the size needed during initialization

```
public ArrayList<String> getallvegetable() {
    String [] columns = new String[]{KEY_VEGETABLES};
    Cursor C =ourdatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    int ivegetable = C.getColumnIndex(KEY_VEGETABLES);
    int iprice = C.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE);

    for(C.moveToFirst(); !C.isAfterLast(); C.moveToNext()){
        result.add(C.getString(ivegetable));

    }
    return result;
}
```

Hope you understand now!

Comment: i couldn't understand your question

Comment: public ArrayList<String> getallvegetable() method worked fine but
in main class m geting error at
 vegetableitem[i] = info.getvegetablenames();
saying the method getvegetablenames is undefined for type vegetabledatabase... plz plz help...need to solve dis problem in an hour or early..mind not working

Comment: For god's sake, please complete your question ;)

Comment: You have to make the return type compatible. When you return a String from a method, your method return type would be String. if you are returing a String array, then the return type would be String[]. Similiarly, when you receive the value by invoking the method, the receiving variable should be of same type

Answer (score 0):

You can use the answer provides by octopus or by passing the id to it like

```
for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++){
    strArray[i] = info.getvegetable(i);
    }
```

Or you can alter the method so that it returns a string array like below

```
    public String[] getvegetablenames()throws SQLException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID,KEY_VEGETABLES,KEY_PRICE};
            Cursor c= ourdatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null,null, null, null, null);
int i=0;
String[] values=new String[c.getCount()];
c.moveToFirst();
            do{

                values[i] = c.getString(1);
               i++;
            }while(c.moveToNext());
            return values;
        }
```

The above code may have errors but it is enough for you to get started